# Regular expression add space around all occurrence of a character within parentheses in python

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to  separate dashes between parenthess. For example: "Mr. Queen (The-American-Detective, EQ), Mr. Holmes (The-British-Detective) "

I want the result to be

"Mr. Queen (The - American - Detective, EQ), Mr. Holmes (The - British - Detective) "

My code is

```
re.sub(r'(.*)(\(.*)(-)(.*\))(.*)', r'\1\2 \3 \4\5', String)
```

however, this code seems only separates the last dash occurs in the last parentheses of a string.

it gives the result "'Mr. Queen (The-America-Detective, EQ), Mr. Holmes (The-British - Detective) "

Can anyone help with it? I tried to find through here; but it seems my code should work the way I expected

Comment: I'm sorry, are you just trying to add extra spaces? Could you please clarify your question and give more examples?

Comment: @AlanSTACK I'm trying to add extra space by using re.sub to separate the dash within bracket

Comment: And what problem are you running into? Your example shows it working perfectly.

Comment: @AlanSTACK; it gives the result "'Mr. Queen (The-America-Detective, EQ), Mr. Holmes (The-British - Detective) " where only the last bracket and the last dash been added space while I'm trying to add space for all dash that appear within the bracket

Comment: I'm currently on the road right now, but this is a problem due to your regex matching the largest possible number of characters by default (e.g. being greedy)

Comment: @AlanSTACK is there anyway to change that default for this particular line?

Comment: You could just use regex to match everything outside, the parentheses, and everything in the parentheses. Then replace all occurences of `-` in the stuff in the parentheses. Using `(.*)\((.*)\)` then combine it all back afterward. Otherwise fixing it to work the other way is hard. But if you want the other way play with the regex on https://regex101.com/

Comment: And to do non-greedy (lazy) you can change `*` to `*?`.

Comment: @AlecC Thanks for reply;  I tried to change * to *?, it gives my result quit different; 'Mr. Queen (The - America-Detective, EQ), Mr. Holmes (The - British-Detective) ' it detects the first dash in bracket but fails to detect the second in the same bracket.

Comment: @AlecC could u be more specific by regex to match everything outside then comine ?? I'm quit confused

Comment: So I tried doing it with lazy but its a problem with how exactly the matching is occuring. You'd need to move the `\(`and `\)` outside your regex to look more like `(.*)\( ... \)(.*)` but getting the insides to match everything is proving tricky.

Comment: And if you use this regex `(.*)\((.*)\)` it will match group 1 as `Mr. Queen` and group 2 as `The-American-Detective, EQ`. Then you can just substitute all `-`'s in the group 2 match to `_-_` (underscores are spaces). Then combine everything back together.

Comment: @AlecC Please avoid answers like "Then you can just...". Nobody comes to stackoverflow for those types of responses. They come for solutions.

Comment: @AlanSTACK literally, what the currently highest voted solution does. And breaking problems into smaller sub-problems is the easiest way to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code achieves the task by dividing it into two separate parts instead of relying solely on a single regular expression.

1. It searches the string `target` for portions that are enclosed by `(...)`
2. It then searches and replaces each `-` with `(SPACE)-(SPACE)` in each found `(...)` using [replacement functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub)

Here we have the solution code:

```
def expand_dashes(target):
    """
    replace all "-" with " - " when they are within ()

    target [string] - the original string

    return [string] - the replaced string

    * note, this function does not work with nested ()
    """
    return re.sub(r'(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))', __helper_func, target)

def __helper_func(match):
    """
    a helper function meant to process individual groups
    """
    return match.group(0).replace('-', ' - ')
```

Here we have the demo output:

```
>>> x = "Mr. Queen (The-American-Detective, EQ), Mr. Holmes (The-British-Detective)"
>>> expand_dashes(x)
>>> "Mr. Queen (The - American - Detective, EQ), Mr. Holmes (The - British - Detective)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Many specifiers in most regular expression implementations (including Python's) act *greedily* - that is, they match as much of the input string as possible. Thus, the first `.*` in your regex is matching all of your input string except for the very last set of parentheses - that first `.*` "eats up" everything it can while still leaving enough left for the whole regex to make a successful match. Once inside that set of parentheses, you first have another `.*`, which similarly matches everything it can and still have the rest of the regex have enough for a successful match - so all the dashes in that final pair of parentheses except for the last dash. Thus, the substitution only inserts spaces around the final dash in the final set of parentheses, because your regex only has a single non-overlapping match: it matches the entire input string, it's just that the part of the regex that singles out dash-between-parentheses only includes the final such dash.

To fix this, you may need to reevaluate parts of your approach, because `re.sub` will substitute for *non-overlapping* matches, and it would be difficult (I'm skeptical it would even be doable) to construct a single regex that can match arbitrary numbers of dashes between a given pair of parentheses, with a corresponding replacement that puts spaces around each such dash, and still make each of those matches non-overlapping (with a regex system capable of arbitrary-number group captures, maybe, but as far as I am aware Python's implementation only captures the last captured group of any repeatable group (`(<group>)*` or `(<group>)+` etc) in a given match. Checking for parentheses surrounding dashes with regex will need to include them in the match, which means a regex that matches and performs a replacement for a single dash-between-parentheses will have overlapping matches where there are multiple dashes in the same pair of parentheses.

An incremental approach, while a bit more complicated in implementation, might be a better way to get the desired behavior. You could use `re.split` with an appropriate regex to split the string into parenthesized sections and the intervening non-parenthetical sections, then perform a regex replacement on only the parenthetical sections using a simpler regex like `r'([^-]*)(-)([^-]*)'` to match any dashes*, then reassemble the full sequence with the new parenthetical sections. This effectively breaks the 'individually capture all dashes within parentheses' problem which is a bit hard for a single regex to get the captures right for into two problems of 'find parenthesized sections' and 'individually capture dashes', which are easier problems to solve.

*Note that this regex suggestion uses the character class `[^-]` meaning 'any characters that are not `-`'. This avoids the issue displayed by your current regex of `.*` including dashes in what it matches and "eating up" all but the last ones, because `[^-]*` is forced to stop matching when the next character is a `-`. Simply replacing `.*` with `[^-]*` in your current regex won't solve the issue, however, because `re.sub` won't replace for matches that overlap, like multiple dashes within the same parentheses would in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try a **simpler** way:

```
import re
s = "Mr. Queen (The-American-Detective, EQ), Mr. Holmes (The-British-Detective) "
s = re.sub(r'(\w+)(\-)(\w+)(\-)(\w+)', '\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5', s)
print(s)
```

Outputs:

```
Mr. Queen (The - American - Detective, EQ), Mr. Holmes (The - British - Detective)
```

Here is the **working**:

- `\w` essentially is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` that is it matches
  lowercase, uppercase, digits or underscore.
- `\-` matches `-`.

So, this regex matches any string of the form `something-anything-anotherthing` and replace it with `something - anything - anotherthing`

Comment: sorry; but this code only works when there are dashes? In general case, when dealing with a sentence for language process, we can't make that assumption. Also, it doesn't seem to work in the first bracket

Comment: @ElleryL No, you are mistaken. This works whatever may be the case (whether or not there is dash).

Comment: sorry, I mean it seems only works for when there are two dashes appears, but what if there are more than 2 dashes?

Comment: I assumed you require solution for case like `a-b-c`.  Maybe, I should've generalized.